# Masonry, not resizing Height, only width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm kind of new to masonry. I have it on my website to display some images, but i have a problem with it. It's not resizing height, only width. My images are inserted like this :

```
<a class="element" href="<?php echo add_query_arg( array( 'image' => $image['id'] ), get_permalink() ) ?>" style="height:<?php echo $image['thumb'][2]; ?>px;background: transparent url('<?php echo $image['thumb'][0] ?>') no-repeat 50% 50%; background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-webkit-background-size:cover;">
```

I've tried to remove the height from the style, and to put it 100% but still no resizing. Just the width is resizing when i make the browser window smaller.

And when i look at my website on a bigger screen, the height is still the same, and it's starting to crop from the image, but the width is still resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess but it looks like you might want to be using:

```
echo $image['thumb'][1]
```

instead of:

```
echo $image['thumb'][2]
```

Seeming as it is a base 0 array.

Comment: the width is set on thumb[1], and the height on thumb[2]

Comment: try removing the style attribute altogether and see if it works then. if so add each rule one at a time until it stops working. its likely due to the height and background image css

Comment: i removed the "height" not displaying, i replaced the "height" with the width, still not working. i made the height a fixed size, displaying, but not resizing. And i don't want any crop of the image, i want to resize any time i  modify the browser size